Certbot renew certificate which covers mutilple domains, one of which no longer exiists
I have a single certificate which I use with 14 websites - each having a different domain. I need to renew this but "certbot renew" fails because one of these websites has closed and the domain no longer exists. How can I update the certificate to remove the unwanted site (and then renew it)
Thx.
Running on Ubuntu 20.04.6
When I tried to renew I got "Challenge failed for domain {...}"

you need to create a new certificate without the unwanted domain.  This can be done using the normal creation command, listing each desired domain name

The domain that no loger exists can be registered. Choose a domain-hoster of you choice, register the domain (again) and set the domain's ip to your server's.

Thanks, I was able to generate a new certificate and get Apache switched over to use it.
